# Android Development: Styling the application

Tags: android-development

How do you approach theme and styling of an Android application? I have all the functionality and I'm now styling and dealing with colors, etc. This is my first big time Android app, and it seems like a huge pain writing some XML, rebuilding and running the app on my phone, looking at results, most likely sighing, and redoing the process.

Is there a better routine for styling/designing an android app?